# A simple probability problem

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Given a person, the probability of it being a male is 30%, and the probability of a male being taller than 160cm is 60%. For a female person, the probability of being shorter than 160cm is 70%. Given that a person is taller than 160cm, what's the probability of this person being a male ?

My attempt of a solution is:

Probability of a person being taller than 160cm: $P(\text{tot}) = P(\text{m}) + P(\text{f})$,
where:

$P(\text{m}) = P(\text{male}) \cdot P(\text{male} > 160\text{cm}) = 0.3  \cdot  0.6 = 0.18$

$P(\text{f}) = P(\text{female}) \cdot P(\text{female} > 160\text{cm}) = 0.7  \cdot 0.3 = 0.21$

so we have $P(\text{tot}) = 0.39$

than the probability asked by the problem should be $P\text{(m})/P(\text{tot}) \approx 0.46$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T$ (tall) be the event that a person is taller than 160 cm. $M$ to be male and $F$ to be female. So we know $P(T| M)= 0.6$ and $P(M)=0.3$ and $P(T|F)=0.3$. $P(F)=0.7$ follows from the assumption that the total population consists only of male and female so that $P(M) + P(F)=1$

We are asked for $$P(M|T) = \frac{P(M \cap T)}{P(T)}$$

$$P(T) = P(T|M)P(M) + P(T|F)P(F) = 0.6 \times 0.3 + 0.3 \times 0.7$$

while $$P(M \cap T) = P(T|M)P(M) = 0.6 \times 0.3$$

substituting we get $P(M|T) = \frac{18}{39}$, which is about the same as your answer, obtained in a different way.

Comment: that's definitely more nicely and neatly written !

Comment: @LBaco That's how we learnt it in high school...

Answer (score 0):

You can divide it as follows: If there are $100$ people in the population,

 $30$ are male, $70$ are female.

 Out of those thirty males, $60\%$, i.e. $18$ are taller than $160$ cm.

 Out of the $70$ females, $70\%$, i.e. $49$ are shorter than $160$ cm (other $21$ are taller, assuming no one's height is $160$ cm)

 Now there are $18+21=39$ tall people. Out of those, $18$ are male. So the required probability is $${18\over39}={6\over13}\approx0.46$$
It's a lot easier doing it this way instead of involving sets; but use whatever works for you

Comment: There are $70$ women.

Comment: @JMP Sorry, my bad. I edited in the correction